# Safely interrupt -reindex?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, synchronization

My database became corrupted and I had to reindex:

```
bitcoind --daemon -reindex
```

It takes my computer quite some time and CPU power. It's been running for an hour but it will take at least 4 more hours to finish. With this high a load, I can't do my work on it, so I'd like to interrupt this process without losing the current progress, and continue later. Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can just stop `bitcoind` (using `bitcoin-cli stop`, or just killing it with SIGINT). Next time invoke it without `-reindex`, and it will continue from where it left off. If you do pass `-reindex` again, it will start over.

Comment: If on Unix, you could also suspend it by "killing" with SIGSTOP, and then "kill" with SIGCONT to resume.

Comment: I have started reindex and after 92% done and again same error come

Comment: What error? It may be CPU overheating, or a disk error. Bitcoin's validation is very intensive.

Comment: This didnt work for me... I did a `-reindex` and Syncing headers reached approx 75%. Closed and restarting without -reindex and it caused it to start downloading and overwriting my blocks.